# "eksctl create cluster" command is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

When executing this command,I get this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>eksctl create cluster --name eksctl-demo --profile myAdmin2
Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request send failed, Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout
```

myAdmin2 IAM users credientials are set up as follows:

**Credentials file:**

```
[myAdmin2] 
aws_access_key_id = ******************
aws_secret_access_key = ********************
```

**config file:**

```
[profile myAdmin2]
region = us-east-2
output = json
```

myAdmin2 has access to the console:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>aws iam list-users --profile myAdmin2
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "myAdmin",
            "UserId": "AIDAYYPFV776ELVEJ5ZVQ",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::602313981948:user/myAdmin",
            "CreateDate": "2022-09-30T19:08:08+00:00"
        },
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "myAdmin2",
            "UserId": "AIDAYYPFV776LEDK2PCCI",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::602313981948:user/myAdmin2",
            "CreateDate": "2022-09-30T21:39:33+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I had problems working with myAdmin that's why I created a new IAM user called myAdmin2.
myAdmin2 is granted `AdministratorAccess` permission:
[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiUpo.png)

aws cli version installed:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.35 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

My Env variables:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= ***********the same as I have in credentials file
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=~/.aws/config
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=myAdmin2
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
AWS_PROFILE=myAdmin2
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****************the same as I have in credentials file
AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
```

I think those are all the necessary things I have to mention. If someone can help, please. I can't move on with this error!!

Answer (score 1):

It worked finally! everything was well configured, I just had to reboot my laptop and it resolved the issue!